# How to add an internal link to navigation and jump to a specific section of the target page (anchor link) in Sulu?

Tags: sulu

I am using [Sulu](https://sulu.io/) as CMS and I want to add an *internal* link to the main navigation, but the browser should scroll to a specific section of the page.

I do not see any way to add the "#..." part to the internal link.

As a workaround I can use an external link, where I can specify the complete URL. But I prefer using the internal link feature.

Any ideas? I have installed Sulu 2.5.10.

Answer (score 0):

In Sulu's slack channel I got the answer that this is currently not possible.

So I stick with the workaround, that I add a property with some validation to my XML template where the editor can add a slug:

```xml
<property name="section_id" type="text_line">
    <meta>
        <title lang="en">Section ID (for anchor jumps)</title>
        <info_text lang="en">Allowed characters are letters, digits, plus and minus signs.</info_text>
    </meta>
    <params>
        <param name="pattern" value="^[\w\+\-]*$"/>
    </params>
</property>
```

This value is used as `id` in the HTML element in the twig template.

Then I add an external link to the navigation, where I specify the complete URL together with the section ID.